# Bash script order files size

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

I would like to order a list of files by their size, but comparing it with a specific number (another file size) being the rule to compare the absolute distance.

This has to be done with a bash script.

For instance:

```
Size to compare: 5
List of files sizes: { 1, 2, 6, 10, 5 }
Result: {5, 6, 2, 1, 10 }
```

I am far from being an expert in bash coding, so I would appreciate some help here.

Comment: How is that result order arrived at? What's the logic here?

Comment: I suppose that It's the absolute difference to 5 (0, 1, 3, 4 ,5).

Comment: Yep, the difference between the size to compare and the other sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
size=5
source=(1 2 6 10 5)
for i in ${source[@]}; do j=$((i-size)); echo ${j/-/} $i; done | sort -n | cut -d " " -f 2 | tr "\n" " "
```

Output:

```
5 6 2 1 10
```

This solution also uses Schwartzian Transform mentioned by chepner.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```
printf "%d\n" 1 2 6 10 5 |
   # Decorate
   perl -ne 'printf "%d %d\n", abs($_ - 5), $_' |
   # Sort
   sort -k1,1n |
   # Undecorate
   awk '{print $2}'
```

I'm only using Perl because it's the shortest way I could think to access an absolute value function.

Answer (score 1):

Perl can be called from a bash script, since it's installed everywhere.

`perl -e '$n=shift; @A=split/,/,(shift); print join ", ", sort {abs($a-$n)<=>abs($b-$n)} @A' 5 1,2,6,10,5`

output:

```
5, 6, 2, 1, 10
```

`$n` is set to your number 5 using `shift`
Array `@A` is set by splitting the input string using commas as a delimiter
The array is printed using a custom sort function `sort {abs($a-$n)<=>abs($b-$n)}`

---

Variation assuming your input file sizes are on separate lines:

`printf "%d\n" 1 2 6 10 5 | perl -ne 'BEGIN{$n=shift} push @A, $_; END{print join "", sort {abs($a-$n)<=>abs($b-$n)} @A}' 5`

output:

```
5
6
2
1
10
```